# I want to sort using commons-collections4-4.0 ComparatorChain

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-beanutils, apache-commons-collection

When we use the latest commons-collections4-4.0jar, we get an error message as shown below regarding making a sort option with a usage of the ComparatorChain and the BeanComparator. Do you have any idea what's wrong with this?  We use commons-bean utile-1.9.2.jar for beanutils.

#### ■success code (commons-collections-3.2.1.jar)

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void testCommonsChain() {

   ComparatorChain comparator = new ComparatorChain();

   List<TestDataBean> testDataBeanList = this.createTestDataBeanList();

   comparator.addComparator(new BeanComparator<TestDataBean>("name"), true);
   comparator.addComparator(new BeanComparator<TestDataBean>("kngk"));
   Collections.sort(testDataBeanList, comparator);

   this.printData(testDataBeanList);

}
```

#### ■failure code (commons-collections4-4.0.jar)

```
private void testCommonsChain() {

    ComparatorChain<TestDataBean> comparator = new ComparatorChain<TestDataBean>();

    List<TestDataBean> testDataBeanList = this.createTestDataBeanList();

    comparator.addComparator(new BeanComparator<TestDataBean>("name"), true);
    comparator.addComparator(new BeanComparator<TestDataBean>("kngk"));
    Collections.sort(testDataBeanList, comparator);

    this.printData(testDataBeanList);

}
```

#### error log

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/comparators/ComparableComparator
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanComparator.<init>(BeanComparator.java:87)
    at logic.TestComparator.testCommonsChain(TestComparator.java:36)
    at logic.TestComparator.executeComparator(TestComparator.java:19)
    at myTestOrange.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.comparators.ComparableComparator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You are looking for a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to what's wrong with it: looking at the [POM](http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.2/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.pom) file, commons-beanutils-1.9.2 depends on commons-collections-3.2.1. The problem is that common-beanutils references classes that are no longer available in commons-collections-4.4.0.

Comment: Note that it is healthy and normal to use Commons Collections 3.x and 4.x in the same project. The packages do not overlap. Even in 2022, the latest `commons-beanutils:1.9.4` still wants `commons-collections:3.2.2`.

Answer (score 0):

That's all well and good but collections v3 suffers from CWE-674 - Uncontrolled Recursion (https://devhub.checkmarx.com/cve-details/Cx78f40514-81ff/).  This issue is addressed in v4. So you are putting your application at risk by using bean utils until they decide to update it.